# Getting polynomial regression to overfit with TensorFlow

Tags: regression, python, tensorflow

The Sklearn documentation contains an example of a polynomial regression which beautifully illustrates the idea of overfitting ([link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html)).
[image: Underfitting vs. Overfitting]

The third plot shows a 15th order polynomial that overfits the simulated data. I replicated this model in TensorFlow, but I cannot get it to overfit. 
[image: Replication with TensorFlow]

Even when tuning the learning rate and the numbers of learning epochs, **I cannot get the model to overfit. What am I missing**?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def true_fun(X):
    return np.cos(1.5 * np.pi * X)

# Generate dataset
n_samples = 30
np.random.seed(0)
x_train = np.sort(np.random.rand(n_samples)) # Draw from uniform distribution
y_train = true_fun(x_train) + np.random.randn(n_samples) * 0.1
x_test = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y_true = true_fun(x_test)


# Helper function
def run_dir(base_dir, dirname='run'):
    "Number log directories incrementally"
    import os
    import re
    pattern = re.compile(dirname+'_(\d+)')
    try:
        previous_runs = os.listdir(base_dir)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        previous_runs = []
    run_number = 0
    for name in previous_runs:
        match = pattern.search(name)
        if match:
            number = int(match.group(1))
            if number > run_number:
                run_number = number
    run_number += 1
    logdir = os.path.join(base_dir, dirname + '_%02d' % run_number)
    return(logdir)


# Define the polynomial model
def model(X, w):
    """Polynomial model 
    param X: data
    param y: coeficients in the polynomial regression
    returns: Polynomial function Y(X, w)
    """
    terms = []
    for i in range(int(w.shape[0])):
        term = tf.multiply(w[i],  tf.pow(X, i))
        terms.append(term)
    return(tf.add_n(terms))

# Create the computation graph
order = 15
tf.reset_default_graph()
X = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")
w = tf.Variable([0.]*order, name="parameters")
lambda_reg = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[])
learning_rate_ph = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[])
y_model = model(X, w)
loss = tf.div(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y-y_model)), 2) # Square error
loss_rg = tf.multiply(lambda_reg, tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(w))) # L2 pentalty
loss_total = tf.add(loss, loss_rg) 
loss_hist1 = tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
loss_hist2 = tf.summary.scalar('loss_rg', loss_rg)
loss_hist3 = tf.summary.scalar('loss_total', loss_total)
summary = tf.summary.merge([loss_hist1, loss_hist2, loss_hist3])
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate_ph).minimize(loss_total)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


def train(sess, x_train, y_train, lambda_val=0, epochs=2000, learning_rate=0.01):
    feed_dict={X: x_train, Y: y_train, lambda_reg: lambda_val, learning_rate_ph: learning_rate}
    logdir = run_dir("logs/polynomial_regression2/")
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir)
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        _, summary_str = sess.run([train_op, summary], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        writer.add_summary(summary_str, global_step=epoch)
    final_cost, final_cost_rg, w_learned = sess.run([loss, loss_rg, w], feed_dict=feed_dict)
    return final_cost, final_cost_rg, w_learned


def plot_test(w_learned, x_test, x_train, y_train):
    y_learned = calculate_y(x_test, w_learned)
    plt.scatter(x_train, y_train)
    plt.plot(x_test, y_true,  label="true function")
    plt.plot(x_test, y_learned,'r', label="learned function")
    #plt.title('$\lambda = {:03.2f}$'.format(lambda_values[i]))
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


def calculate_y(x, w):
    y = 0
    for i in range(w.shape[0]):
        y += w[i] * np.power(x, i)
    return y


sess = tf.Session()
final_cost, final_cost_rg, w_learned = train(sess, x_train, y_train, lambda_val=0,
                                             learning_rate=0.3, epochs=2000)
sess.close()
plot_test(w_learned, x_test, x_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Remove the regularization / l2-penalty.

Comment: Thank you @sascha. In the above code, the regularization constant is set to zero. I was afraid that due to rounding issues it may still be a tiny positive constant that provides a small regularisation. To test this, I minimized the unregularised square error 'cost' directly. Even then I could not get it to over-fit.

Comment: @sjdh Shouldn't `w = tf.Variable([0.] * order, name="parameters")` be `w = tf.Variable([0.] ** order, name="parameters")`? i.e. with two `*`.

Comment: Thank you @josh. With 'order = 5',  `[0.] * order` results in a list `[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]`, which I use to initialize the coefficient variable `w`. The power operation `**` is included in the function `model` (`tf.pow`).

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem about this. When I do polynomial regression, I also can't overfit the data by using GD in Tensorflow.

Then I compare the coefficients(weights) of the model by using sklearn LinearRegression, I found when the polynomial degree is larger the coefficient of high order is very smaller(i.e. 1e-4), and the low order is relative large(i.e. 0.1).

That's mean when you using GD algorithm for searching the best value of weights, the high order coefficient become extreme sensitive about the value change, and the low order coefficient is not.

And I guess the best coefficient(overfit with data) of low order term is large, and of high order term is tiny. When you set large learning rate, it's impossible to find the right answer, and when you set tiny learning rate, you need lots of iterations.
It's obvious when you using GD algorithm with small data set to make overfit.